# What does TIF_NEED_RESCHED do?

Tags: linux-kernel

What is the purpose of **`TIF_NEED_RESCHED`** in a Linux scheduler (say CFS)? In case of writing a new scheduling class, can this flag be used? If yes, where and how can this flag be used for a new scheduling class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TIF_NEED_RESCHED` is one of the thread information [flags](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.10.10/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h#L68). It tells that the `schedule` needs to be called while interrupt and userspace return paths. See the `__schedule` function description [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.10.10/kernel/sched/core.c#L2913)...

Answer (score 2):

`TIF_NEED_RESCHED` is set to signal that a, usually currently running, task needs to be re-scheduled so that the core the task is running on, becomes available for other tasks. In other words: the TIF_NEED_RESCHED flag is set if it has been determine that the task has used its time slice and should be preempted. For reasons, setting the flag and actually preempting the task is done at two different occasions and points in time. For example the flag may be set in an interrupted handler but the actually re-scheduling is done at a later point.

Side node: TIF stands for "Thread Information Flags".

Answer (score 0):

TIF_NEED_RESCHED is set for an active process which needs to be preempted in order to schedule another process from the queue (or an idle process).
On each system tick, check_preempt_tick() is called which checks if the task has run long enough to give a fair chance to another process in need. It then calls resched_curr to set the flag.
However, the task is not to be preempted suddenly. Preemption happens at certain points like interrupt exits. So, when the timer exits, the flag is checked and the scheduler entry schedule() is called.

Answer (score -1):

TIF_NEED_RESCHED is one of the many “thread information flags” stored along side every task in the Linux Kernel. One of the flags which is vital to the working of preemption is TIF_NEED_RESCHED

Answer (score -2):

I think if you rewrite the scheduler you can use this flag as value but you will implement what you do of it.